# How can I get the value of a ReactiveVar without invalidating the computation it is in?

Tags: meteor

According to the official Meteor documentation, a ReactiveVar only has .get() and .set() methods. How can I retrieve the value of one without causing it to invalidate its context's computation? Preferably without calling external functions.

Example:

```js
//...
  this.autorun(() => pleaseRunMeOnce(this.reactiveThing.get()) );
//...
```

Ideally I'm looking for a way to do this using only ReactiveVar, maybe by accessing its internals, even if it is not documented.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "without causing it to invalidate" when using just the .get() function? .get() will only computate if not already done and return the current value of the reactive var. If you call .get() 10 times it won't recompute when not invalidated by other events.

Comment: I mean when you call .get on a reactive var from inside an autorun, for example. Doing that will cause the autorun's computation to become invalidated every time that reactive var gets set.

Comment: "computation to become invalidated every time that reactive var gets **set**." That is the wished behavior of a reactive var. Maybe you won't use a reactive var but more something like a context var? Reactive is Reactive.

Comment: @TomFreudenberg Imagine a black box setup hooked up to a bomb. But you trip and fall into the black box! Oh no! Now there is no way in or out, except through a single, ReactiveVar-shaped hole on one side, and the return slot on the other! Thinking quick, you push a note out through the return slot on your right, that reads "Send help, I'm stuck in a black box". Your prayers are answered! You hear a `Ding!` and a ReactiveVar labeled "Key" slides in. But! You put to your ear, and the soft hum of a restless var changing constantly. Oh no... if you get the key, the bomb outside will explode!

Comment: @TomFreudenberg and that's the exact moment when your phone rings. It's a text message from your father. He says 'Maybe you won't use a reactive var but more something like a context var? Reactive is Reactive.' Meanwhile, you hear a rumble. The Computation has been Re-Computed. You hear the bomb's clock go `counter--`.

Comment: I am sorry to troll you and get trolled by you. I don't know anything of you real coding problem except what you have written in your question. So just wanted to give another aspect of thinking about your problem. I actually never was in a situation where a ReactiveVar shouldn't be Reactive. So forgive my 2cents - and good luck to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[`Tracker.nonreactive(func)`](https://docs.meteor.com/api/tracker.html#Tracker-nonreactive)**  does the trick.

It returns whatever `func` returns, and it also ignores reactivity within it.

Like so:

```js
//...
  this.autorun(() => Tracker.nonreactive(pleaseRunMeOnce(this.reactiveThing.get())));
//...
```